# How to create Elastic index via debezium which depends on multiple tables in a consistent manner

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I have a RDBMS consisting of 3 tables,

- Projects, PK ProjectID
- Tasks : contains ProjectID and PK TaskID, TaskTitle, and several other attributes
- TaskData : contains TaskID, and a json which essentially is the form data for the task

So a Project comprises of several Tasks, and each Task has an associated TaskData.

I want to put all this info together into Elastic search (ES) so I can do queries like "Return all Projects where Task with "*Title A*" "*field X*" is "*Y*" and so on. Doing this requires me to build a single denormalized document in ES. I will use debezium to populate the kafka topic, and then a kakfa consumer can push the data in ES.

Doing it consistently though requires all the above 3 tables (with different schema) to be put into a single Topic (I know how to do that via SMT Transform). Trying to have 3 separate topics would mean I lose the ordering between the CRUD event records across tables. For instance, when a Project is created, first the Project table entry would be inserted, followed by one Task entry and then Task Data entry, for each task. If I read records in 3 separate topics, I will never be able to guarantee order in which I consume as expected correctly.

This is where I have the doubt. This seems like a fairly straightforward and common usecase. Is this how its done (putting events from different tables, each having different schema, into single Topic using SMT)? If not, whats the usual way to do it?

Comment: You could use Kafka Streams to join topics before you use Kafka Connect. An SMT won't know some records should be associated with others and I don't think the ES connector does partial updates

Comment: But joining may cause out of order merging isn't it? I would want to preserve the order in which I recieve the records, and they should be the order in which dB changes have happened..

Comment: You can setup different joining windows or sessions, depending on your needs. Connect/Debezium definitely cannot do that, either.

Comment: @Ouroboros were you able to find any pattern for doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately no